# Use of Getter and Setter

Tags: getter-setter

Why do we use getter and Setter methods. Could u tell me the real importance of these methods.

```
public int getArea()
{
   return this.area;
 }
  public static void setArea(int area)
 {
    this.area=area;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is to encapsulate the objects' variables. It is useful mainly not to give direct access to whoever may need to get or set those fields. For example, when using the setter method, you can implement controls on the parameter, thing that can't be done when setting the field directly.